# Play SWF files one the iPhone

Tags: iphone, flash

I am new to the iPhone development, I need to develop application in which I can load SWF files (shock wave file). I have done lots of research but I couldn't get it to work. How do I load it on the iPhone ? if it's not possible, what alternatives do I have ?

Comment: iphone doesn't support flash. for phone development use java

Comment: @yamikoWebs iOS doesn't support Java either.

Comment: then use objective-c or their own dev kit. Their are plans for java on the iPhone. Just waiting for the official jvm release.

Comment: @yamikoWebs Interesting, do have any links or further info on the "plans for java on the iPhone"?

Comment: in short they recently changed policy's that make it very likely to happen. http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/apple-lets-in-java-and-flash-should-android-be-worried/2091 is one of many sites talking about how the new policy's can allow java once a jvm is written for it. it's also just a likely flash will soon be suported without the need of jailbreaking the phone.

Comment: @yamikoWebs OK, I see what you mean. The removal of the restrictions mentioned in that article, that was made about a year ago, is what made it possible to use AIR/Flash to develop stand-alone apps for iOS, as DarkDust says in his answer here. Something similar could be done for Java. There's for example MonoTouch for c#, that is also "in the clear" since the restrictions about what languages and tools that could be used was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone doesn't support flash.

Comment: i dont telling about flash but is there any way that play swf in flash

Comment: There is no way to play flash content on any iPhone/iPad for now.

Comment: i have publish 4 app with flash content but it is build in adobe air.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not flash, it's compiling it to native iPhone code. [related](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is no Flash player on iOS and no other solution to play Flash in your app. However, you might want to look into [Adobe AIR for iOS](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air_for_ios.html) which is able to produce iOS apps.

Comment: I doubt it. It's a programming language (like Java) but has the ability to *produce* SWF files, not convert them (as far as I can tell). So you would need to *port* you SWF to HaXe first. While it seems you can write in HaXe and target iOS, the better solution would be to write in Objective-C if you have to start from scratch or port an existing app. Everything else will always be trying to catch up with Apple's APIs and introduce additional bugs.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Nowhere on their site they state that they can parse SWF and turn it into something else. See for yourself: http://haxe.org/doc/intro

Answer (score 1):

iOS Doesn't support Flash so you won't be able to launch a swf. If you have the source for the SWF you could consider building an ios app through Flash CS5+. Also, you could try porting it to [haxe](http://haxe.org/), which is very similar to actionscript and should allow you to build for both Android and iOS at once.

Comment: Basically these options apply if you have the source files for the swf (so the .fla project and .as source code files). These are compiled to produce an swf - you will need this source code to recompile for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no such application (expect Frash, which is only available on jailbroken iPhones) which can load SWF Files on an iPhone.

The only way you can go is to convert that file in an iPhone readable format, which I can't recommend as the results are normally horrible.

Otherwise I suggest to recode the behaviour of that SWF File in Objective C or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Flash player in iOS. Even more – it is forbidden by Apple iOS Developer Agreement to deploy them (and other technologies where you may use an app to execute another executable code of any kind (SWF, Java, AIR, etc.) on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your own flash player.