# SWF files not working on IPhone/IPad

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, css, flash

I have a swf file on my site and it doesn't work on Iphone/Ipad

Is there any way to handle this .swf in my code to work

Thanks

Comment: Is this a serious question? Please just Google for "iOS no flash" or similar.

Comment: Wow...ok yeah a Google search is definitely going to enlighten you. Flash + iOS = Nope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play SWF files one the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833596/play-swf-files-one-the-iphone)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS [doesn't](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) support Flash, so you need to use Html5 instead.

You can try [Swiffy](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) to convert an swf file into Hmtl5 or [Wallaby](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/wallaby/) to convert a fla file. But note that both tools are still a work in progress and may not work for you.

Also, you can always write the html5 version yourself.

Comment: I tried swiffy ,but it can't convert the swf to html and here's the result  
1- The ActionScript class StyleSheet is not supported.
2- The ActionScript class XML is not supported.
3- The ActionScript property TextField.autoSize is not supported. (8 occurrences)
4 The fscommand action is not supported. (2 occurrences)
5- Filters are not supported by (Mobile) Safari. (4 occurrences). While the wallaby uses only .fla  not swl . Thanks for your support but i need more help

Comment: note adobe wallaby supports only Flash Professional CS5 *.fla/*.xfl  format and swiffy can't convert a file that's more than 512k

Answer (score 0):

iOS devices do not support Adobe Flash.

Instead, you should, like almost all other Flash sites, check if Flash is present and if it isn't, then present alternative content, whether it's HTML5 or something.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a swf file on my site

If your swf is **not interactive**, one solution is to convert the SWF to video and use the HTML5 `<video>` tag to embed it into your website.

If this solution could work for you, try using **Flabaco** [flash-banner-converter.com](http://www.flash-banner-converter.com) to convert the swf to video; Flabaco is an online converter and generates WebM, MP4 & OGG video files, at-least one of which will play in all popular HTML5 browsers including that on the iPad.

Of course, the above isn't applicable for interactive flash content.

Kayo
(Flash-Banner-Converter.com)

Answer (score 0):

The U-tube application for ipad can play swf files