# Is there an alternative to swf on a webpage?

Tags: html, iphone, flash

I have a page that has an swf on it.

Is there a cross browser wrapper (to make it also compatible with apple - iphone, ipad)?

I have heard of the term 'wrapper'. Tell me if I am wrong.. (not html5/Javascript as this is an swf as og (open graph) video to be put on facebook. I've got quite confused over the answers over swf wrappers on google)

Comment: "Wrapper for SWF to work on iPhone and iPad" and "without HTML5" is kind of impossible.

Comment: And you base that upon what?

Comment: I've seen swf work on iphone as an app, surely for web this is possible!?

Comment: maybe they should also ban javascript lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash does not work not on iOS, nor Windows Phone, nor Android (even though you can install it manualy)

iOS:
http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/
[SWF files not working on IPhone/IPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875732/swf-files-not-working-on-iphone-ipad)
Adroid
http://youtu.be/iLjLbm_nBU8

So basically, if you want your SWF content available on all platforms, you'll have to re-develop it in HTML5.

Comment: so when does facebook alow html5 video embeds (I thought they don't allow javascript to run)

Comment: They actually look for videos in the provided link and extract them. Then they just use info they extracted in a safe way, with or without JavaScript, it's up to them.