# jQuery webcam plugin not working with mobile browsers

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, webcam

Hi I am using [this](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) plugin in my application which is going to use in android browsers also. I got a message that on firefox that 'plugin is needed' when i go to adobe for flugin then it says no plugin available for the device. with chrome on android it says this plugin is not supported...

what I suppose to do? How it will work on cellphone and tablet also?

Comment: If you need to access camera for mobile browser, just provide `<input type="file">` control. Android itself provides options for Camera, Gallery or other files.

Comment: @ShaunakD Thaks this works. I removed plug in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution will never work in mobiles, here is why.

```
$("#camera").webcam({
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    mode: "callback",
    swffile: "/download/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
    onTick: function() {},
    onSave: function() {},
    onCapture: function() {},
    debug: function() {},
    onLoad: function() {}
});
```

this `jscam_canvas_only.swf` which is a flash object can't not [work in mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875732/swf-files-not-working-on-iphone-ipad).